# possible to use steroids and css icon sets?

Tags: android, cordova, steroids

is it possible to use css icon sets like font-awesome with steroids?

Currently if i preview my stuff in a web browser, the icons are rendered as expected but in my android devices nothing shows up

Answer (score 0):

There is no support of FontAwesome. You need to export do PNG the icons that you will use.

https://muut.com/appgyver#!/steroids-native-ui#fontawesome-as-tab-icons